# How to install conky themes?

Tags: conky

I' m asking how to install conky themes that you download from the Pling store as zip and extract as folders on Linux.

I tried to rename the file name `[name]. conf` with `Anything.conkyrc` and then copy and paste the folder to `home/. conky`, but opening Conky Manager2 does not display the theme I am looking for. The conky in question is `Regulus-Dark-PlyrctlF-2.6`.

Comment: What is the "Pling store"? When you say `home/. conky` do you mean `$HOME/.conky`? That is, is this a _directory_ called `.conky` inside your home directory? Or did you really mean a directory named `. conky` inside `/home`? Do you have a `~/.conkyrc` file?

Comment: The /. conky dyrectory is created when I install conky Manager. The Pling Store is an olline themes store for Linux and Open-source, avaible at: https://www.pling.com/

Comment: What is the `/. conky` directory? Please [edit] your question and make sure to use the right path. Do you really mean a directory under root (`/`) whose name starts with a `.` and then a space and then the word `conky`? Or do you maybe mean a directory under your home directory whose name is `.conky` with no space? What are the contents of the zip file you downloaded? What file name did you rename? Did you really rename to `Anything.conkyrc`? Please [edit] your question and explain what you are doing showing us the _specific_ and _exact_ commands used.

Comment: Did you carefully read through and follow the [How to apply](https://closebox73.wordpress.com/2024/01/02/how-to-apply/) installation instructions linked on the [Regulus Dark - Conky theme](https://www.pling.com/p/1955473/) page?

Comment: Yes, i did. i also tried to install the Mintaka Conky, with the same result.